# Must a leading curly brace be escaped in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash

```
regex="\{foo"; string="{foo"; [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo "true"
```

This is a bash script that works in Bash 3.x and 4.x. If the "\" is removed then it stops working in Bash 4.x. Is this behavior expected and/or a bug? the regex(7) man page suggests the escape is not required. Do other flavors of regex require that curly brace be escaped?

Comment: It works for me here with bash 3.2; presumably the regular expression rules changed when going to 4.  Are extended regular expressions the default, perhaps?

Comment: `[[ "$string" =~ '{'foo ]] && echo "true"` will also print "true".

Comment: @anubhava the behavior here is different in bash 3 and bash 4, so just giving an example of behavior isn't useful without specifying which version

Comment: @Sparr: I have both BASH versions in my systems but since you quoted `Bash 4.x` I provided you an example from `Bash 4.1.2`

Answer (score 6):

The opening brace needs to be escaped, because it denotes the start of the quantifier - `{m,n}`. I haven't used any regex flavour, where it works without escaping `{`. But, I can't comment for all of them. But the reason is quite logical.

For the same reason, you would need to escape the opening bracket - `[`, because it denotes the start of a character class.

Comment: regex(7) says that a curly brace followed by something other than a digit is not a quantifier.

also, implicitly it can't be a quantifier because there is nothing preceding it

Comment: @Sparr. Hmm. Well that may differ depending upon the regex flavour. I'm talking in general. Haven't used bash though. I'll search for this issue related to bash.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) says (*emphasis mine*):

> An additional binary operator, ‘`=~`’, is available, with the same
>   precedence as ‘`==`’ and ‘`!=`’. When it is used, the string to the **right**
>   of the operator is considered an **extended regular expression** and
>   matched accordingly.

As such, the `{` in the regex needs to be [escaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended).

However, you can force `bash` to perform a string comparison by quoting the string on the rhs of the `=~` operator.

```
$ regex="{foo"; string="{foo"; [[ $string =~ "$regex" ]] && echo "true"
true
```

Comment: You don't actually give any information on why the { needs to be escaped.

The info on string comparison is interesting, but I'm only interested in regex matching here.

Comment: @Sparr It seems that you didn't observe the link that elaborates why metacharacters need to be escaped in extended RE.

Comment: @Sparr To elaborate further, try this: `echo "foo { bar" | grep "{"`, `echo "foo { bar" | grep -E "{"`, and `echo "foo { bar" | grep -E "\{"`.

Comment: for me all three of those greps match, using GNU grep 2.5.1. I did observe the link, but it is not relevant. The { in my regex is not part of a quantifier, so it doesn't have to be escaped in a BRE or an ERE.

Comment: All three would *seem* to match, but do you know what they really match.  The second *doesn't match* the `{` in the string.  That was the point.  I'm not sure if I've been able to explain.

Comment: @Sparr Add a `-o` to all the three `grep` commands.  Might make easier to figure.

Comment: all three match just the {

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35880/discussion-between-sparr-and-devnull)